# Why is this code running showing SIGKILL error?

Tags: c++, c++11

the code runs printing **94601019043208** in endless lines and then shows  SIGKILL error.please help me out handling this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    long long int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t>0)
    {
        long long int l,r,x,y;
        cin>>x>>y>>l>>r;
        long long int res;
        if(x>y)
        res=x;
        else
        res=y;

        long long int sum,i;
        for(i=res;i<=r;i++)
        {
            sum=((x&i)*(y&i));
            if(sum==(x*y))
            break;
        }

        cout<<i<<endl;
        t=t-1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are your inputs? What output do you expect?

Comment: x=7;y=12;l=0;r=50 and all always positive.So the answer would be 15

Comment: I'm getting 15. Cannot replicate.

Comment: Please put the data in the code.  There is no need for input statements if you know the data that is causing the issue.

Comment: Same here, I get 15, don't see any problems. Seems the code could be a lot simpler. If I'm understanding it right `cout<<min((x|y),r+1)<<endl;` would produce the same output.